# Unit Test for a function with API call in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jasmine

I have a utility function defined in my `utils.tsx` file:

```js
// resolveAxiosInstance creates an axios instance
const createAxiosInstance = resolveAxiosInstance();

export const getItemList = params => {
    const axios = await createAxiosInstance;
    const res = await axios.get("/my-url", {params});
    return res.data;
}
```

And I am using the `getItemList` utility in my component `mycomponent.tsx`. It is invoked on click of a button but before calling that API the click event sets some states as well. Here's the code of my component:

```js
export const MyComponent = () => {
    //rest of component code
    const clickMe = () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const data = {
            // item and price are vars whose values are filled by user through input text
            itemName: item,
            itemPrice: price,
        };
        getItemList(data).then(res => {
            if (res)  {
                setItemData({
                    itemName: name, 
                    itemPrice: price, 
                    itemDiscount: res.disc,
                });
            }
        }, err => console.log(err));
    }
    return (
        //rest of the component code
        <div>
            <Button onClick={clickMe} data-testid="update">Click Me</Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I want to write a unit test case in Jasmine to test the on click functionality. I am able to invoke the on click function by using `simulate("click")` on the button element. But it doesn't execute the API call and that's understandable. To execute the API call I tried to use `spyOn` but it didn't help. It returns the error that `getItemList is not declared configurable`. Here's my test case:

```js
it("should show data on click me", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
    let elem = wrapper.find(MyComponent);
    const mockSpy = Jasmine.createSpy("getItemList").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(mockResp))
    let btn = elem.find('[data-testid="update"]');
    btn.at(0).simulate("click");
    elem = elem.update();
    expect(elem.find("table").length).toBe(1);
});
```

My question is how can I write a unit test for my use case where I trigger a button click and it calls a function which does something, and then calls an API and updates the table on my view as per the API response.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock fetch or XMLHttpRequest which used by axios.
jasmine has official [jasmine-ajax](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-ajax) library which allows mocking XMLHttpRequest object **but not** fetch. I think that in 99% axios will pick the `fetch` instead of old XMLHttpRequest so I recommend to use something like [`fetch-mock`](http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/)

```js
it("should show data on click me", /*⚠️*/async () => {
    /*⚠️*/fetchMock.mock('/my-url', {data: {disc: 'foo'}});
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
    let elem = wrapper.find(MyComponent);
    let btn = elem.find('[data-testid="update"]');
    btn.at(0).simulate("click");
    elem = elem.update();

    // because fetch async we should wait response
    expectAsync(/*⚠️*/(await waitFor("table")).length).toBe(1); 

    function waitFor(selector) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
           checkSelector();
           function checkSelector() {
             const result = elem.find(selector);
             if (result.length) return resolve(result);
             setTimeout(checkSelector);
           }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the use of `mockSpy` here?

Comment: It does nothing, so you can just remove it

Comment: I tried this but it still didn't work. It gave a 404 error as it made an actual API call with the wrong domain name like `https://test/my-url`.

Comment: I guess that you got 404 because not properly stub URL in my example '/my-url' relative to the page origin where tests are running. If you go to another domain you should use something like `https://test/my-url`. But I recommend reading the documentation for fetchMock or similar solution.